# Unload from Redshift to S3 fails

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, data-dump

I'm running the following command in Redshift:

```
myDB=> unload ('select * from (select * from myTable limit 2147483647);')
       to 's3://myBucket/'
       credentials 'aws_access_key_id=***;aws_secret_access_key=***';
```

Here is what I get back:

```
ERROR:  S3ServiceException:The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed
        using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this 
        endpoint.,Status 301,Error PermanentRedirect,Rid 85ACD9FFAFC5CE8F,
        ExtRid vsz4/0NdOAYbaJ48WYCnrYBCvuuL0cBTdcEN

DETAIL:  
-----------------------------------------------
error:  S3ServiceException:The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed
        using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this 
        endpoint.,Status 301,Error PermanentRedirect,Rid 85ACD9FFAFC5CE8F,
        ExtRid vsz4/0NdOAYbaJ48WYCnrYBCvuuL0cBTdcEN
code:      8001
context:   Listing bucket=myBucket prefix=
query:     0
location:  s3_unloader.cpp:181
process:   padbmaster [pid=19100]
-----------------------------------------------
```

Any thoughts? Or maybe ideas how to dump data from Redshift into MySQL or something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is returned when using path like syntax with a non US bucket. Create a new bucket in the same region as your redshift cluster and everything should work.

Comment: To rephrase a little bit: Redshift cluster and S3 bucket must be in the same region :)

Comment: You can write to a bucket in a different region but you must specify that region when using UNLOAD.

EX:
    
unload ('select * from (select * from myTable limit 2147483647);')
to 's3://myBucket/'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=***;aws_secret_access_key=***'
region: 'us-west-2

Resource:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html#r_UNLOAD-synopsis

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the prefix part of the filename. Try using s3://myBucket/myPrefix

Comment: Documentation also states that: The Amazon S3 bucket where Amazon Redshift will write the output files must reside in the same region as your cluster.

Comment: The error message is returned when using path like syntax when using a non US s3 bucket. Create a new bucket in the same region as your redshift cluster and then everything should work.

Comment: That's the correct answer! Redshift cluster was in Oregon, but S3 bucket in US Standard. Thanks a lot :) Can you please submit it separately and I'll accept it?